# Let $f : [0, \infty) \rightarrow$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = 1 – 2x+\int_{0}^{x}e^{x-t}f(t)dt$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f : [0, \infty) \rightarrow$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = 1 – 2x+\int_{0}^{x}e^{x-t}f(t)dt$.

a) Is $f(1)=2$

b) Is $f(2)=-1$

c) The area of the region $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\text{ x }R:f(x)\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}\}$?

My attempt is as follows:-

$$f(0)=1\tag{1}$$

$$f(x) = 1 – 2x+\int_{0}^{x}e^{x-t}f(t)dt$$
$$f(x) = 1 – 2x+e^x\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}f(t)dt$$
$$f'(x)=-2+e^xe^{-x}f(x)+e^x\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}f(t)dt$$
$$f'(x)+2-f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{x-t}f(t)dt\tag{2}$$

$$f'(x)+2-f(x)=f(x)-1+2x$$
$$f'(x)=2f(x)+2x-3$$

Now we derived a lot of information from the given facts, its time to find $f(1)$

Assuming $(1,2)$ lies on the curve:-

$$2=1-2+e\int_{0}^{1}e^{-t}f(t)dt$$
$$\dfrac{3}{e}-\int_{0}^{1}e^{-t}f(t)dt=0$$

Can it ever be possible? I was not able to analyse this, any way?

Let's check for $f(2,-1)$

$$-1-1+4-e^2\int_{0}^{2}e^{-t}f(t)dt=0$$
$$2-e^2\int_{0}^{2}e^{-t}f(t)dt=0$$

Now here again I was not getting to analyse this whether it can be zero or not.

c) In the given set,how can we ensure that $x$ is not mapped to multiple $y$ because otherwise it will be not the function and we won't be able to use definite integral.

Comment: Just solve the ODE you obtain no?

Comment: What do you mean by ODE?

Comment: Have you studied differential equations?

Comment: no I haven't studied differential

Comment: Oh, so for your information, you can actually solve any equation of the form $$f'(x) + g(x)f(x) = h(x) $$ for f(x) using a standard approach

Comment: https://www.math24.net/linear-differential-equations-first-order/

This link details the approach, with y representing f(x), the function of x you want to find

Comment: What is the source of the problem?